# Не могу установить pyjnius

Tags: python, pip

Необходимо установить pyjnius, но постоянно появляются разные ошибки. Сначала требовал последние версии JDK и JRE, затем Windows10 SDK и C++ Build Tools, после того, как все это установил, появилась новая ошибка. CMD от имени администратора.
Лог:

```
    C:\Users\maxim>pip install pyjnius
Collecting pyjnius
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b6/57/c90acf31322e6417f06c90410dbfcb149633a6006b7efbf99dfebe177c1f/pyjnius-1.2.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.7.0 in c:\users\maxim\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from pyjnius) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cython in c:\users\maxim\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from pyjnius) (0.29.6)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyjnius
  Building wheel for pyjnius (setup.py) ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\maxim\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Windows\\TEMP\\pip-install-g2w3cfa2\\pyjnius\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Windows\TEMP\pip-wheel-cm8u6heh --python-tag cp37:
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201
  WARNING: Not able to assign machine() = AMD64 to a cpu value!
           Using cpu = 'i386' instead!
  JDK_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201

  JRE_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre

  warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
  1 warning
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7
  copying jnius_config.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\jnius
  copying jnius\reflect.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\jnius
  copying jnius\signatures.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\jnius
  copying jnius\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\jnius
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\jnius\src
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\jnius\src\org
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\jnius\src\org\jnius
  copying jnius\src\org\jnius\NativeInvocationHandler.class -> build\lib.win32-3.7\jnius\src\org\jnius
  copying jnius\src\org\jnius\NativeInvocationHandler.java -> build\lib.win32-3.7\jnius\src\org\jnius
  running build_ext
  cythoning jnius\jnius.pyx to jnius\jnius.c
  c:\users\maxim\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:367: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Windows\TEMP\pip-install-g2w3cfa2\pyjnius\jnius\jnius.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  building 'jnius' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\jnius
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\include\win32" -Ic:\users\maxim\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\maxim\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" /Tcjnius\jnius.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\jnius\jnius.obj
  jnius.c
  c:\users\maxim\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: io.h: No such file or directory,
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyjnius
  Running setup.py clean for pyjnius
Failed to build pyjnius
Installing collected packages: pyjnius
  Running setup.py install for pyjnius ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\maxim\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Windows\\TEMP\\pip-install-g2w3cfa2\\pyjnius\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Windows\TEMP\pip-record-zlyy2ajs\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201
    WARNING: Not able to assign machine() = AMD64 to a cpu value!
             Using cpu = 'i386' instead!
    JDK_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201

    JRE_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre

    warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
    1 warning
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    copying jnius_config.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\jnius
    copying jnius\reflect.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\jnius
    copying jnius\signatures.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\jnius
    copying jnius\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\jnius
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\jnius\src
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\jnius\src\org
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\jnius\src\org\jnius
    copying jnius\src\org\jnius\NativeInvocationHandler.class -> build\lib.win32-3.7\jnius\src\org\jnius
    copying jnius\src\org\jnius\NativeInvocationHandler.java -> build\lib.win32-3.7\jnius\src\org\jnius
    running build_ext
    skipping 'jnius\jnius.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    building 'jnius' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\jnius
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\include\win32" -Ic:\users\maxim\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\maxim\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" /Tcjnius\jnius.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\jnius\jnius.obj
    jnius.c
    c:\users\maxim\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: io.h: No such file or directory,
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\maxim\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Windows\\TEMP\\pip-install-g2w3cfa2\\pyjnius\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Windows\TEMP\pip-record-zlyy2ajs\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Windows\TEMP\pip-install-g2w3cfa2\pyjnius\
```

Аналогичная ошибка в PyCharm:
[image: PyCharm]

Comment: Вам вариант с `.whl` не помог?

Comment: @gil9red как раз хотел сейчас написать, что скачал готовое колесо pyjnius и установил его с помощью команды  'pip install [директория]/pyjnius.whl', затем из папки python на диске C:\ скинул в свой проект, а именно в папку venv библиотеку pyjnius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все-таки сам разобрался с проблемой. На данном сайте https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ скачал готовое колесо pyjnius и установил его с помощью команды 
`pip install [директория]/pyjnius.whl`